# JavaScript fromCharCode/charCodeAt

Tags: javascript

Нужно найти str в данном фрагменте кода. Думаю, что нужно как-то выполнить код в обратном порядке, но не знаю, как.

```js
String.fromCharCode((str.split('').map((c, i) => c.charCodeAt(0) - i % 10))) ===
            'TxnbO^lbhk-emoaq_k' /* find str ? */
```

Знающие люди, помогите, пожалуйста, иначе я ночью не усну

Comment: Это задача от Яндекса

Comment: Это задача от Яндекса...

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае от кода символа отнимают фиксированное число (от 0 до 9). Таким образом, чтобы получить исходный код символа - нужно просто прибавить это же число.

В итоге получим строку: `'TypeScript-forever'`

Пример:

```js
console.log(
  String.fromCharCode(...('TypeScript-forever'.split('').map((c, i) => c.charCodeAt(0) - i % 10))) ===
  'TxnbO^lbhk-emoaq_k' /* find str ? */
)
console.log(
  String.fromCharCode(...('TxnbO^lbhk-emoaq_k'.split('').map((c, i) => c.charCodeAt(0) + i % 10)))
);
```

Comment: Задача в отборе на вакансию Яндекса)

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси, на стажера что ли? :)

Comment: Это было типо капчи в финтех)